# How do I mask/encrypt data in a view but maintain uniqueness of values?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

Say I have a column in a SQL Server table with the following entries:

```
+----+
|id's|
+----+
|489 |
|633 |
|251 |
|633 |
+----+
```

I would like to provide a view to colleagues that masks/encrypts this column but still allows for uniqueness in values, i.e. :

```
+----+
|id's|
+----+
|xx  |
|zz  |
|yy  |
|zz  |
+----+
```

What is the best function for achieving this result?

Comment: will it works if just generate a running no ? `dense_rank() over (order by id)`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: "I would like to provide a view to colleagues that masks/encrypts this column but still allows for uniqueness in values" - OK...But why? Do you have an XY problem? What human is going to check thousands of values for uniqueness?

Comment: Do the masked values need to be stable over time? E.g. are these users expecting to be able to take one of these values and re-identify the same row at a later date, no matter what changes have happened in the meantime (so long as the id has remained the same)

Comment: @MitchWheat the reason is just for them to compute things like frequency of the unique values in that column. While they won't know that 633 specifically appears 2 times, for example, they'll know that zz appears twice.

Comment: create another lookup table. everytime a new values is seen, generate a random value, add entry to lookup and use use random value in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to use a hash function. We want a collision-free hash, which of course doesn't exist, but most cryptographic hashes are collision free for all *practical* purposes. So:

```
declare @t table (id varchar(30))
insert into @t(id) values
('489'),
('633'),
('251'),
('633')

select id,HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',id)
from @t
```

Which produces:

```
id    
----- --------------------------------------------------------------------
489   0xE4BE97CE765E6CFCD703884CC31DB7478FA7BEFCA7CF6DC15420BA20ED718ABE
633   0xB6B1B469EA43C90A602E7AE3BDEA001B11F66C17337DEC23DF0B0249542357EE
251   0xC75D3F1F5BCD6914D0331CE5EC17C0DB8F2070A2D4285F8E3FF11C6CA19168FF
633   0xB6B1B469EA43C90A602E7AE3BDEA001B11F66C17337DEC23DF0B0249542357EE
```

Of course, some people are going to complain that these are overly long to use a mask values - but be aware that any truncation of these to shorter values increases the risk of collisions. Whether collisions are acceptable to you only you can decide.

Comment: Thank you. I see you had to declare values 489, 633, 251 and 633 again. How can this be done for an entire column without having to explicitly state these values?

Comment: @VyktaWakandigara - I'm declaring those values because I needed a sample data to run my query against - and I don't have access to your table. The top half of my script (creating `@t` and populating it) could easily have been *included in your question* as sample data. Note that it takes up about as much space as your presentation of the sample data but it's *runnable*.

Comment: Yes I see. I ran the same query and it returned some Chinese-looking characters. Is there a way to get text as you have there? When the text looks machine-unreadable, I'm unsure if I can prove that I have achieved unique masks.

Comment: " but most cryptographic hashes are collision free for all practical purposes." - birthday paradox withstanding....  I wouldn't use a hash if you have to guarantee the frequency of those values...

Comment: @MitchWheat What would you use instead? I was just looking for a functional solution, one that avoids lookup tables.

Comment: see the comment I added to your question.