# How do I mask certain values and maintain uniqueness while using a case...when statement in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, data-masking

Say I have a column in a SQL Server table with the following entries:

```
+----+-----+
| ids| col1|
+----+-----+
|4   | a   |
|4   | b   |
|4   | a   |
|4   | b   |
|5   | a   |
+----+-----+
```

I'd like to mask the `ids` column given that `col1 = a`. However, I'd also like to maintain the uniqueness of the `ids` masking, so the result would look as follows:

```
+----+-----+
| ids| col1|
+----+-----+
|XX  | a   |
|4   | b   |
|XX  | a   |
|4   | b   |
|YY  | a   |
+----+-----+
```

I have used  a case...when with SHA2_256 algorithm to maintain uniqueness as in this post:
[How do I mask/encrypt data in a view but maintain uniqueness of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811135/how-do-i-mask-encrypt-data-in-a-view-but-maintain-uniqueness-of-values?noredirect=1#comment92540890_52811135)

,but then the resulting mask are 'Chinese-looking' characters that seem machine-unreadable. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Would numbers be OK?

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ids int, 
    col1 char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(4, 'a'),
(4, 'b'),
(4, 'a'),
(4, 'b'),
(5, 'a')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN col1 = 'a' THEN CHECKSUM(CAST(Ids as varchar(11))) ELSE ids END As ids, 
        col1
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
ids     col1
136     a
4       b
136     a
4       b
137     a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query  (Replace #test with your actual table name), In future case can come where you need to include other characters too in addition to just 'a'.

Below List table will help you with that.

```
create table #list
(
col1 varchar(1)

)

insert into #list values ('a')

 select case when isnull(b.col1,'0')<>'0' then a.col1+cast ( Dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY a.col1 ORDER BY a.col1 ASC) as varchar(max)) else cast(a.ids as varchar(max)) end as ids, 
a.col1  from #test a
left join #list b
on a.col1 =b.col1
```

Out Put

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested masked output values of `XX` and `YY` are perhaps misleading, because if you have millions of `id` values in your table, then two letters won't be able to uniquely/randomly cover all data.  One option here might be to use `NEWID()` to generate a unique UUID for each `id` group:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, NEWID() AS mask
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT t2.mask, t1.col
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

If you don't want to show the entire UUID, because it is too long, then you may instead show a substring of it, e.g. for just the first 5 characters:

```
SELECT LEFT(t2.mask, 5) AS mask, t1.col
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

But keep in mind that the shorter you make the UUID being displayed, the greater the probability that two different `id` groups would be rendered with the same mask.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up doing. Using the example provided by @Zohar Peled, but making the adjustment that the `ids` column is a varchar, we can make the table as follows:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ids varchar(150), 
    col1 char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(4, 'a'),
(4, 'b'),
(4, 'a'),
(4, 'b'),
(5, 'a')
```

and then do the following:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN col1 = 'a' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(150),HashBytes('SHA2_256', ids),2) ELSE ids END As ids,
col1
FROM @T
```

This more closely resembles the initial solution in the link, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide IDs also by integer numbers (don't know if it's secure enough in your case)

```
CREATE TABLE #t (ids int, col1 char(1));
INSERT INTO #t VALUES
(4, 'a'),
(4, 'b'),
(4, 'a'),
(4, 'b'),
(5, 'a');
```

Query

```
SELECT ISNULL(t2.num, t1.ids) AS ids, t1.col1
FROM 
    #t t1 LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ids, col1) + (SELECT MAX(ids) FROM #t) AS num, 
        ids, col1 
    FROM #t 
    WHERE col1 = 'a' 
    GROUP BY ids, col1) t2 
        ON t1.ids = t2.ids AND t1.col1 = t2.col1;
```

Result

```
ids                  col1
-------------------- ----
6                    a
4                    b
6                    a
4                    b
7                    a
```